# Netbeans 8.1 + tomcat 8.0.39 build-impl.xml 1045 error

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans-8

I get this error when I try to deploy my web application:

> Deployment is in progress...
>
> deploy? 
>   config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FEDGE%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext3172741505011533351.xml&path=/mywebapp
>
> FAIL - Unable to create directory [C:\Program
>   Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\conf\Catalina\localhost] 
>   C:\Users\EDGE\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mywebapp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045:
>   The module has not been deployed.  See the server log for details. 
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)

How do go about solving this error??

Comment: look into the server log as the message sugest you. Maybe you will see what is wrong

Comment: Server log is currently empty

Comment: Solved. Moved tomcat away from program files directory, gave tomcat administrative privilege, gave startup.bat in conf  tomcat directory administrative privilege and bam! It worked.